# Why is the :not() not working when I want to exclude child-element from being the hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple code:

```
<div class='card'>
  <div class='upper-body"> .. </div>
  <div class="lower-body"> .. </div>
</div>
```

I want when you hover over the upper-body, a border to be added on the entire card, but when you hover over the lower-body, nothing to be added. The upper-body is basically the entire card, and the lower-body is the button at the bottom of the Card.

I tried this:

```
 .card { 
    &:hover:not(.lower-body) { 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #0A8276;
   }
}
```

..but it's not working. Border is added even when I hover over the lower-body. Why? Why is it not excluded?

Comment: It's `:not` not `.not`.

Comment: Oops. Just a typo.

Comment: Just to be clear. I tried with `:not()`, and not `.not()`. I just made a typo when writing the snippet, for which I got immediately punished with a downvote.

Comment: Try `&:not(.lower-body):hover`

Comment: Your selector, once the SCSS/SASS-style `&` is resolved, is `.card:hover:not(.lower-body)`. Of course that always applies (when hovered) - your `.card` element does _not_ have the class `lower-body`.

Comment: @CBroe right.. so how do I make it work?

Comment: @user21616350 I just told you, your selector is wrong, use `&:not(.lower-body):hover`

Comment: [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), if you can live with it not working in Firefox (unless specifically enabled by the user.) If not, then you will have to find a different solution - for example a positioned pseudo element for `.lower-body`, "emulating" a border around the card, that gets triggered via `.lower-body:hover`

Comment: @Baruch You told me it's wrong, but you didn't tell me how to make it right.

Comment: @CBroe If it's not supported in all major browsers, then it's not useful for me. So what else can I do?

Comment: _"So what else can I do?"_ - I made an alternative suggestion already, did I not?

Comment: @CBroe Where? You made no workable suggestion, only pointed out why it's not working.

Comment: So the whole _"If not, then you will have to find a different solution - for example [...]"_ part of that same comment in which I mentioned :has(), is somehow not visible to you?

Comment: @CBroe This was your only solution, was it not? I told you that if using `:has` does not work on major browsers, then I cannot use it. What else can I do (besides using :host)?

Comment: No, that was not the only solution I suggested. Are you not clear on what "if not" means, or what exactly is the issue here with realizing that?

Comment: I realize the Javascript tag is missing, but would using Javascript be an option?

Comment: @CBroe I don't want to use a pseudo-element. This should not be this difficult to do.

Comment: @Gerard I don't want to use JS. Is there really not another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors.

1. `<div class='upper-body">` starts with ' and ends with "
2. `.card { &:hover:not(.lower-body) {` means that you write it for the .card element and not for its children - you shouldn't use the & character.

Use this code:

```css
.card>div{
  border:5px solid;
}
.card div:not(.lower-body):hover{ 
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #0A8276;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="upper-body"> .. </div>
  <div class="lower-body"> .. </div>
</div>
```

For SCSS the code is this:

```
.card { 
  div:not(.lower-body)&:hover { 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #0A8276;
  }
}
```

Or if it's supposed to be all on hover, then this code:

```css
.card>div{
  border:5px solid;
}
.card:hover div:not(.lower-body){ 
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #0A8276;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="upper-body"> .. </div>
  <div class="lower-body"> .. </div>
</div>
```

For SCSS the code is this:

```
.card { 
  &:hover div:not(.lower-body) { 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #0A8276;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want when you hover over the Card, the border of the `upper-body`, border-color of the Card becomes green, which includes the `lower-body` part of the Card. But if you hover over the `lower-body`, border-color of Card does not change. In your snippet, this does not happen.

Comment: If you want to change parent element .card when is hover his child (lower-body), it is not possible.. That's not how CSS works, you can't set style for parent while is hovered his child. The element must be split or use JavaScript.

Comment: @maťo it is possible with :has, but this is not widely supported yet

Comment: The simplest (supported) solution would probably be via jQuery: $('.upper-body').mouseenter(function(){ $('.card').addClass('greenborder') }) $('.upper-body').mouseleave(function(){ $('.card').removeClass('greenborder') })

Comment: I don't use jQuery.

Comment: You can try something like this by using :before https://jsfiddle.net/t3qh4nba/

Comment: Is there a way to make sure hovering over the border is excluded?

Comment: Already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is possible with :has. But this is not widely supported yet.

```css
.card:has(.upper-body:hover) {
  border: 1px solid #0A8276;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="upper-body"> Hover Me </div>
  <div class="lower-body"> Lower Body </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's not supported in all major browsers, then it's not going to be useful for me. So what else can I do?

Comment: It's more just for reference for future viewers of the question when it is more supported.

Answer (score -2):

there is no way to style an element based on its children hover state.
you can get your desired look by 2 way:

1.add a class using javascript to card when user hover on upper-body and then set border style based on this class.

2.use upper-body::after this way:

```
.card,.lower-body {
    position: relative;
}
.upper-body:hover::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```